# How to post a node data to drupal server from android application?

Tags: android, web-services, drupal-7

[image: The attached screen shot shows the node JSON data format on drupal server]

Now I want to create this node from android application. For this I am sending data in the form of key value pairs by putting them into a json object. When I post this json object I am getting these errors:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized : CSRF validation failed & ["CSRF validation failed"]

I am using this code:

```
try {
JSONObject birthDateJSONObject = new JSONObject();
                birthDateJSONObject.put("day", 28);
                birthDateJSONObject.put("month", 02);
                birthDateJSONObject.put("year", 2015);

                JSONObject endDateJSONObject = new JSONObject();
                endDateJSONObject.put("day", 28);
                endDateJSONObject.put("month", 02);
                endDateJSONObject.put("year", 2015);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("title", titleEditText.getText().toString().trim());
                jsonObject.put("type", "charity");
                jsonObject.put("uid", uid);
                jsonObject.put("charity_amount", 200);
                jsonObject.put("person_birthdate", birthDateJSONObject);
                jsonObject.put("charity_org", organizationEditText.getText().toString().trim());
                jsonObject.put("message", messageEditText.getText().toString().trim());
                jsonObject.put("person_registered", false);
                jsonObject.put("charity_enddate", endDateJSONObject);

StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                stringEntity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity); 
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {

                Log.d("Encoding Exception",e.toString());
            }

            try {

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                if(httpResponse.getStatusLine() != null && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 401) {

                    Log.d("Submission failed ", httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
                }

                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
                try {

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    String json = sb.toString();
                    Log.d("Response", json);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                Log.d("Protocol Exception",e.toString());
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {

                Log.d("Protocol Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Obtain the session token at `/services/session/token`

Step 2. Set a header containing the `X-CSRF-Token=SessionTokenHere` before doing `httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);`

Comment: I am already setting session token, cookie etc before the try block of above given code. The code is as follows:

Comment: HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");
         httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
         httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         
         httpPost.setHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
         httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", session_name + "=" + session_id);

Answer (score 0):

As you have used JSON to send data 
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
must be httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");